# Filter on a foreign key which is the current class

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

I have a tree structure model which is :

```
class XMLStruct(models.model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('XMLStruct')
    # other attributes
```

My aim is to get the leaves of the tree, it means that this is all entries which can't be found in the parent attribute. I tried to do this with Queryset but I don't know how to do something like :

```
leaves = XMLStruct.objects.filter(parent__not_in = XMLStruct.objects.all().parent)
```

Does anyone have a clue ? I could build the tree by giving the children instead of the parent but I found this representation better.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this :

```
parents = XMLStruct.objects.all().values_list('parent',flat=True)
all = XMLStruct.objects.all()
result = list(set(all) - set(parents))
```

It's not elegant but it works. If anyone have a better solution, please feel free to answer !

Answer (score 0):

This will do exactly what you want in a single query:

```
class XMLStruct(models.model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('XMLStruct', related_name='children')
    # other attributes

leaves = XMLStruct.objects.filter(children=None)
```